# Folder Permission on mounted NAS storage

Tags: mount, ssh, sftp, nas

I created an SFTP Server with Jailed Folders. I want to move these Folders on a mounted NAS Storage. My issue is the right Folder permissions that come from the mount. The Linux Box is connected with Active Directory, so users and groups get delivered from there.

Folder Structure how it should be:

```
Appdata                      <- root:root 755
Appdata/SFTPdata             <- root:root 700
Appdata/SFTPData/%h          <- root:root 755
Appdata/SFTPData/%h/upload   <- user:usr-sftp 700
```

When i now mount the NAS Storage with

```
mount -t cifs -o user=admin,gid=13371337,rw,forcegid,domain=DOMAIN.lan,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770  //storage.DOMAIN.lan/SFTPTestUnix /Appdata/
```

as root, all Folders in the mounted drive are now set as root:usr-sftp (the gid is the AD group usr-sftp) with chmod 770 (coming from file and dir_mode).

Question: How can I workaround this issue. Is there a better way to do this? Im currently using cifs, is nfs more suitable for this?

Comment: did you already try uid=#####

Comment: i have multiple users each with theyr own home folder jailed, adding a uid means that the mounted drive is attached to the user? but the download folder should have set the permission for each user itself. or am I missing here something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution to this issue.
CIFS (as using the SMB standard) is not able to forward local root permissions. NFS is, as long as you set no_root_squash. In my case I am using NetApp and I can activate SuperUser forwarding what solved my issue.